# `NullReferenceException` : `Context` con not be `null` if Setting `InputTransparent = true` in the sub-control

Tags: c#, android, maui

Hi friends I have an `Exception` problem, :-(
do you have any good ideas?

#### `InputTransparent` Exception : Context can not be null

- Occurs when the controls are nested.

```xml
<!--controls are nested -->
<ContentPage.Content>
    <local:SampleView>
        <local:SampleView.Content>
            <local:SampleView2>
                <local:ContextNullException />
            </local:SampleView2>
        </local:SampleView.Content>
    </local:SampleView>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

```
public ContextNullException()
{
    InputTransparent = true;
}
```

#### Environment

`Platform` : *Android*
`SDK` :  7.x

Sample Link : https://github.com/SSstupid/Question-list/pull/7

Comment: Does it happen if you nest `ContextNullException` in many `ContentView`s?

Comment: @ Riccardo Minato, Yes,  `Layout<View>` in `ContentView`

Comment: May I ask why you use a Layout<View>? Why not a StackLayout or a Grid?

Comment: I'm migrating legacy. Just someone used `Layout<View>` before and If there is a change, I need to manage the ripple effects, so I want to finish it without a big change as much as possible.

Comment: Well, if i use StackLayout then no error. You could also refer to [Create a Custom Layout in Xamarin.Forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/custom).